# Access buttons in Activity from card view

Tags: android, button, android-activity, material-design, android-cardview

I am new to android, I am sure solution will be very easy but I am wasting my time on it.

Constraint layout is used with card view inside it.

I have two separate card view with buttons inside them. When I try to access the buttons it gives me NPE.

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LandingPage"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/signupCard"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loginCard"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="@string/signUp"
        android:textColor="#DE000000" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/loginCard"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signupCard">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#DE000000" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Code:

```
  private   CardView signUpCardview;
        private   Button signUp;
         signUpCardview= new CardView(this);
            signUpCardview = (CardView)signUpCardview.findViewById(R.id.signupCard);
            signUp= (Button)signUpCardview.findViewById(R.id.signup);
```

I am getting the below error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v7.widget.CardView.getContext()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Have you tried: signUp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

Comment: ill post it as an answer then. you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
signUp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
```